# I can't click on edit and delete buttons

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

Everything was going OK. I was able to click on 'edit' and 'delete' buttons. Suddenly I decided to create a slide over so that users can edit their info. When I was finished I discovered I'm unable to click on those 2 buttons. I don't know what happens if I hover.
Here's the code: https://github.com/nsursock/themusicstop-client/blob/main/src/components/users/ListingPanel.vue
PS: I tried adding a z-index to buttons but that didn't solve the problem.
[image]

Comment: Please don't provide a link to the code links for code are only to show your project. Provide the code in the question.

Comment: it's pretty big

Comment: Please try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This ensures people will easily understand and reproduce the problem so they can be better able to provide help.

Comment: problem solved : I also had to show/hide the main div.